# Limiting upload file size, maximum uploads in one request, and file type within the PHP script file itself

Tags: php

I've been dealing with a small problem that requires me to individually define maximum upload file size, limit maximum uploads in one POST and file types on a per-script basis. This means that I can't use the .htaccess file or php.ini to define `max_post_size` and other parameters that limit what can be uploaded.

The script is just used to upload and store images on a publicly viewable webserver. The upload script works in tandem with ShareX. I eventually want to give access to hosting to a few others, so I want to limit the types that they can upload, how much they can upload in one request, the file size of their images.

How would I add these parameters to the script itself instead of using server configurations to limit everyone?

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$secret_key = "REDACTED"; //32-char
$sharexdir = "REDACTED";
$domain_url = "REDACTED"; 
$lengthofstring = 7;
$space= "\x20";
$linkembedu2800 =؜;

function RandomString($length) {
    $keys = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'));

    $key = '';
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}

if(isset($_POST['secret']))
{
    if($_POST['secret'] == $secret_key)
    {
        $filename = RandomString($lengthofstring);
        $target_file = $_FILES["sharex"]["name"];
        $fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sharex"]["tmp_name"], $sharexdir.$filename.'.'.$fileType))
        {
            echo $domain_url.$sharexdir.$filename.'.'.$fileType.$space.$linkembedu2800;
        }
            else
        {
            echo 'ERROR: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: INVALID SECRET KEY';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR: NO POST DATA RECIEVED';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php the `post_max_size` is only changeable for `PHP_INI_PERDIR`

according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php it can only be done in the php.ini or .user.ini or apache config, or php-fpm config, or .htaccess, ...  not from your php script.

but maybe you can forge something with apache file_match.

```
<FilesMatch script1.php>
    php_value post_max_size 100M
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Turns out my .htaccess file seems to be ignoring the parameters I set... I'll have to ask another question. The parameters I'm using are as follows:
`php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value upload_max_filesize 8M 
php_value max_file_uploads 1`

Comment: .htaccess only works if you use apache2 web server.  with allowOverride.